# RxJava fromCallable() and defer() difference in behaviour

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have implement a validate function, sample code are as below:

```
public class TestObject {
  LocalDateTime d1;
  LocalDateTime d2;

  //getters, setters
}

public class ErrorResult {
  String errorMsg;
  
  public ErrorResult(String errorMsg){
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
  }
}

public Observable<ErrorResult> validate(TestObject testObject){
  // implementation section
}
```

For the implementation section, I have tried to use Observable.fromCallable() and Observable.defer() functions to do the same job, for example:

```
// for implementation using Observable.fromCallable
return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
  LocalDateTime d1 = testObject.getD1();
  LocalDateTime d2 = testObject.getD2();
  if(d1.isBefore(d2))
    return Observable.just(new ErrorResult("Error d1 is before d2"));

  return Observable.empty();
});

// for implementation using Observable.defer
return Observable.defer(() -> {
  LocalDateTime d1 = testObject.getD1();
  LocalDateTime d2 = testObject.getD2();
  if(d1.isBefore(d2))
    return Observable.just(new ErrorResult("Error d1 is before d2"));

  return Observable.empty();
});
```

While the implementation of the logic within the anonymous functions is the same,

- the implementation using Observable.fromCallable throw a compilation error in IDE (Intellij), which stated "no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Observable conforms to ErrorResult". It was caused by the return of Observable.empty() as the fallback return in case no error exists
- the implementation using Observable.defer compile successfully without error

May I know what is the difference between Observable.fromCallable() and Observable.defer() in this case?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromCallable` is not designed to return an `Observable`, while `defer` is. So in your example with `fromCallable`, you're ending up with a `Observable<Observable<ErrorResult>>`. You actually can't get your desired behavior with `fromCallable`, because you can't use it to get an empty `Observable` (returning `null` from the `Callable` results in a `NullPointerException`).

Comment: You are right, I have missed to know the difference of return type between the two operators, thanks for clarifying